# Hide the buttons in the Global Menu (Command) Bar

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365-sales

Global Command bar in the Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement contains some Global buttons like- Search, Task Flow, Relationship Assistant, Quick Create, New Activity, New Record, Advanced find, Import Data etc. I need to turn all those off, if not, most of them. The users don't want to see the menu items that they don't use. 
I've tried using the Ribbon workbench by Scott-Durow but I can't find all the buttons on the Ribbon workbench. I can tweak the solution XML but need to know the actual button names / location / command references so that I can refer them in my `<HideCustomAction>` tags in the `<RibbonDiffXml><CustomActions>` tag.

```
<RibbonDiffXml>
     <CustomActions>
        <HideCustomAction HideActionId="codec.Mscrm.GlobalTab.Tools.TaskFlow.Hide" Location="Mscrm.GlobalTab.Tools.TaskFlow" />
        <HideCustomAction HideActionId="codec.Mscrm.GlobalTab.Tools.RelationshipAssistant.Hide" Location="Mscrm.GlobalTab.New.RelationshipAssistant" />
        <HideCustomAction HideActionId="codec.Mscrm.GlobalTab.Tools.AdvancedFind.Hide" Location="Mscrm.GlobalTab.Tools.AdvancedFind" />
     </CustomActions>
</RibbonDiffXml>
```

Comment: Assuming you are still using the classic UI, not the Unified Interface UI. What do you mean Global Menu bar? Do you mean the dark blue navigation bar on the very top? That's not a ribbon. Ribbons are per entity not global. Why don't you make a Canvas App where you have more control of the UI.

Comment: I'm designing a new App (Unified Interface) and I need to hide the buttons on the navigation bar. ex- task flow, relationship assistant, create new activity etc.

Comment: @Raghu Do you have any followup question?

Comment: I've looked at the Ribbon Xml and couldn't find anything related for those global command bar and also not on the Ribbon workbench. There seems to be no solutions that exists within CRM.

Answer (score 2):

See if this is what you are looking for: (I  could not find Relationship Assistant & Task flow, I assume they are dynamic buttons & maybe unsupported to hide them)

```
<HideCustomAction HideActionId="new.Mscrm.GlobalTab.New.NewActivity.Hide" Location="Mscrm.GlobalTab.New.NewActivity" />
<HideCustomAction HideActionId="new.Mscrm.GlobalTab.New.NewRecord.Hide" Location="Mscrm.GlobalTab.New.NewRecord" />
<HideCustomAction HideActionId="new.Mscrm.GlobalTab.Tools.AdvancedFind.Hide" Location="Mscrm.GlobalTab.Tools.AdvancedFind" />
<HideCustomAction HideActionId="new.Mscrm.GlobalTab.Tools.ImportData.Hide" Location="Mscrm.GlobalTab.Tools.ImportData" />
<HideCustomAction HideActionId="new.Mscrm.BasicHomeTab.Tools.Meqf.Hide" Location="Mscrm.BasicHomeTab.Tools.Meqf" />
```

[image]